# npm -g install weinre on windows azure remote server

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, weinre

Ive been trying to install weinre on Windows Azure server and after downloading node.js and typing in 'npm -g install weinre' I get the following error message in the cli.

```
C:\>npm -g install weinre
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\\\node.exe" "C:\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "-g" "in
stall" "weinre"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: weinre@'*'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["2.0.0-pre-H0WTHDO5-incubating","2.0.0-pre-H1GCS73N-incubatin
g","2.0.0-pre-H3FWTQKQ-incubating","2.0.0-pre-H41DGW8S-incubating","2.0.0-pre-H8
EOSCLN-incubating","2.0.0-pre-H9PU2WST-incubating","2.0.0-pre-HA5N9T49","2.0.0-p
re-HG9PLCRF","2.0.0-pre-HH0SN197","2.0.0-pre-HYFXM3QM","2.0.0-pre-HZ79PDUK","2.0
.0-pre-HZO3BMNG","2.0.0-pre-I0Z7U9OV"]
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log

C:\>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's some kind of bug with recent versions of `npm`, which requires you to specify a version when installing weinre.  Try this instead:

`npm -g install weinre@latest`

Comment: Perfect, this fixed it. Thanks

Comment: this did it for me. Hair pulled for 30 minutes before seeing this.